# Specify a javascript method in an html attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, callback

In a website, I'm using jquery tools.

In a lot of places, I've to do the same action:

When I click on a link, I display a popup:

This is done easily by

```
$(".overlayTrigger[rel]").overlay({
    mask: {
        color: '#111',
        loadSpeed: 300,
        opacity: 0.9
    },

        closeOnClick: true
    }
);
```

But the problem is that I would like, in each case, call a javascript method which loads some data for my popup.

I know there is a parameter of the trigger that I can set:

```
onLoad: function() {
   //Call the method specified in data-load-method attribute
},
```

And my goal is to call my custom method in the `onLoad: function(){}` and the method has to be specified on the `<a href>` through something like an attribute:

```
<a href="#" class="overlayTrigger" rel="#MyPopupDiv" data-load-method="LoadPopupXYZData">Click here for the popup</a>
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You are already using `data`-attributes. If your `a` has an attribute of `data-key="hello"` you can use `$(this).data('key')` to get the "hello". See: http://api.jquery.com/data/ - Or am I missing something?

Comment: where is this method defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, you want to do something like this:

```
onLoad: function() {
   var method = $(this).data('load-method');
   window[method]();
},
```

If not, please clarify.

Comment: `attr()` returns a string, not a function.

Comment: instead of eval: `window[method]()`

Comment: hamczu, just found that out. :) +1

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#" class="overlayTrigger" rel="#MyPopupDiv" onclick="LoadPopupXYZData()">Click here for the popup</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

use click or hover methos like this

```
$(".overlayTrigger[rel]").click(function(){
//inside this method u can access the element using
//$(this) and execute the overlay showing
//also u can accesss the element and its attributes using $(this)
});
```